# StructureGroup IsPublishable property in Tridion 2011

Tags: api, tridion

I would like to know where is now (in Tridion 2011) the old property of the strucure groups "IsPublishable".

Looks like this has changed a bit because I searched for it at the API and I couldn't find a thing. Is not a property any more but now It's necessary to recover this info from a different place?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Glezalex - Congrats on your first SDL Tridion post on SO - If you will be working with SDL Tridion in the future, you might like to know there is a proposal for a dedicated Q&A site at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 Your commitment would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is `StructureGroup.IsActive` property